# ImageSwitcher Adapter inside listview Adapter causes losing of values on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, imageswitcher

I am working on an app,in which i want to add image-switcher in Listview. It causes shuffling on images in imageSwitcher while scrolling the switcher.I google it many time but not get any use full tutorial

my code is :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        holder = new ImageHolder();

        /**
         * layout and its component Initialization
         */
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectedtopicitem, parent,
                false);

        holder.profilename = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilename);

        imageList = new ArrayList<String>();

        holder.postid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postid);

        holder.posttime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posttime);
        holder.commentedimagetext = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.commentedimagetext);
                holder.imagepost = (Gallery) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagepost);
        holder.imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.switcher1);

                holder.imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    context, android.R.anim.fade_in));
            holder.imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    context, android.R.anim.fade_out));

            /*setting adapter for imageswitcher*/
            holder.imagepost.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(context));
            (new ImageAdapter(context)).notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return convertView;

    }
        /*adapter class*/
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private int itemBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
            // ---setting the style---
            TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();

        }

        // ---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() {
            return imageList.size();
        }

        // ---returns the ID of an item---
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        // ---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            imageView.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(display_width,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            try {
                aq.id(imageView).image("http://" + imageList.get(position),
                        true, true, display_width, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return imageView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: have you solved this? because i also try to add imageswitcher inside listview.

Comment: @Hendy yes,,,,,, There was nothing wrong with this code,,,, running superly

Comment: can you provide some xml please.. i want to implement your code so i can achieve like in this link , you can see a listview add image switcher / viewpager with viewpager indicator at row 2, `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.tokobagus.betterb&hl=en`